# Kendu MVC Grid Export to Excel is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendu mvc grid in my mvc application using razor view.
    I have to enable Export to Excel feature of kendu mvc grid. I saw demo of Export to Excel on telerik. I applied the same code from there in my .cshtml but Export is not working.
    here is my grid code for Export to Excel

```
.Excel(excel => excel
             .FileName("Kendo UI Grid Export.xlsx")
             .Filterable(true)
             .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Quotes_Save", "Admin")))
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .PageSize(20)
              .Read(read => read.Action("Quotes_Read", "Admin"))
              ))

public ActionResult Quotes_Read()
        {
            //return Json(GetAllQuotes().ToDataSourceResult(request));
            return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Quotes_Save(string contentType, string base64, string fileName)
        {
            var fileContents = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

            return File(fileContents, contentType, fileName);
        }
```

No ActionResult from both of these called..
This is version of kendo mvc that i am using 2014.3.1316.545
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the jszip link into your page:

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2014.3.xxx/jszip.min.js")"></script>
```

obviously putting your version of the kendo suite you have installed.